# Is it possible to disable the ribbon button based on the stage of Opportunity.?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

User cant close opportunities unless they are at the "Close" stage (on the Business Process Flow) So can we disable the "Close as Won" but still allow “Close as Lost” unless they are not on that part of the flow. If they select Close stage then and then Close as won ribbon button should be enabled?

Is there any way to do so?script,plugin or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field on Opportunity called StepName that you can use; it contains the name of the current step of the Business Process Flow.

An enable rule on the button that includes a JavaScript function should work.

The JavaScript function should perform a REST call to retrieve the StepName attribute.

Have a look at this if you need more info on disabling a ribbon button with a JavaScript enable rule:
http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/11/25/dynamically-disable-ribbon-buttons-in-dynamics-crm/

Comment: Hi, my problem for this is where to add the javascript code. In the refered article it is stated "JavaScript function you have loaded into CRM via a Web Resource". But when I select custom javascript rule I only got a few javascript libraries to chose from and not all libraries I have in my Web Resources. So how to add my own javascript library so I can access it in the custom javascript rule?